# c++ writing data to a given position in an array

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers

I am reading an image with opencv and I want to have an array of images.
This is how I init my array. I need to do it with the new keyword because the array is really big.

```
  unsigned char* imageStack = new unsigned char[frame.cols * frame.rows * channels * numberOfImages];
```

Now I want to write my image to a position in this array. This is how I tried to do it

```
int imageStackIndex = imageIndexPosition * frame.cols * frame.rows *channels;
imageStack[imageStackIndex] = frame.data;
```

But I get this error:
error: a value of type "uchar *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "unsigned char"

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: I hope you have REALLY good reasons to use something as unsafe as a `unsigned char*` buffer instead of, let's say, a `std::vector<cv::Mat>`.

Comment: Why not use std containers?  I recommend using a std::vector<T*>, and define a type T which holds 1 image.  Next, change T* to an smart pointer appropriate for your use.

Comment: @2785528 `cv::Mat` is already a smart pointer/container, so `std::vector<cv::Mat>` would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageStack` is a pointer to to the first of some number of `unsigned char`. `imageStack[imageStackIndex]` selects one of those `char` (or attempts to; it may be out of bounds). Therefore, it is an `unsigned char`.

`frame.data` is presumably a pointer to `unsigned char` or is an array, which is automatically converted to a pointer to `unsigned char`.

Therefore `imageStack[imageStackIndex] = frame.data;` attempts to assign a pointer to `unsigned char` to an `unsigned char`, and that is what the error message complains about.

C++ does not have any feature for copying an entire array by an assignment. If you want to copy the `frame.cols * frame.rows * channels` bytes of image data pointed to by `frame.data` to `imageStack` at the starting offset `imageStackIndex`, then one way is:

```
std::memcpy(&imageStack[imageStackIndex], frame.data, frame.cols * frame.rows * channels);
```

Comment: how i can then write the data to a given position?

Comment: okay thank you . But I want an array of images. Where I can change the data at  given index position. frame.data has for example a size of 10 and when I have 10 images the size of imageStack is 100. Maybe memcopy can help me?

Comment: thank you. I will try it out. The 2 was just an example for an image index.

Comment: @Tobias Out of curiosity, why don't you just use the methods from `cv::Mat` specifically designed to access its content? Like `cv::Mat::at<uchar>(x,y)`.

Comment: @m88 I didnt know I could use it. I like to work with standard types. Now it would be some refactoring to use this. Maybe I will change it to  cv::Mat::at<uchar>(x,y)

Comment: Are the casts necessary? I thought that conversion to `void *` is automatic, as is from anyt `T*`to `const T*`?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: No, I think they are not needed. I was not sure, since C++ is stricter about these things than C, so I put the casts in until I could check. They are edited out now.

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know the possibility exists, there's safer (and faster, since you don't reallocate) ways to access your matrices content.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> mats;
mats.push_back(cv::imread("image1.png"));
mats.push_back(cv::imread("image2.png"));
// etc...
// I would check that mats.back().type() == CV_8UC1 after each push_back so we're sure the following code works...

// reference on the [x=10,y=20] pixel from the 5th matrix in my collection
uchar& pixelRef = mats.at(4).at<uchar>(20,10);
```

And that's it, you're done.

---

Anyhow, in your current implementation I'd suggest you to perform a few checks on your `frame` matrix before copying it to your buffer:

- `assert(frame.data)` to make sure your imread (or acquisition through cv::VideoCapture or whatever) didn't fail
- `assert(frame.type() == CV_8UC1)` since your copy assumes 8bits pixels
- `assert(frame.isContinuous())` so you're certain there's no gap in memory at the end of each row (although it shouldn't happen if directly read from imread)
- `assert(frame.cols == N && frame.rows == M)` with N and M predetermined, since your buffer currently doesn't work with images of varying sizes.